# How to activate r_basicprofile API LinkedIn permission?

Tags: linkedin-api

I have created an app in the LinkedIn Developer Portal, and currently, I have the r_liteprofile permission. I have tried to follow the [LinkedIn documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a526048/accessing-linkedin-apis?lang=en), but I amb unable to find the Marketing Developer Platform box under the Products section to make the request.
[Product's section from LinkedIn Developer Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOlgl.png)